# How to connect ORACLE DB

Tags: java, jdbc

Here I'm trying to connect oracle which is installed in local machine with `DSN bam`.
I'm getting `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver` Exception. Anybody please help me to fix this issue.

```
public class JdbcConnectionExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         try {
                Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
                Connection con = DriverManager
                    .getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:bam"
                        ,"system","tiger");
                Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
                System.out.println("Created DB Connection....");
                ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from tt");
                while(rs.next()){
                    System.out.println(rs.getString("ename"));
                    System.out.println(rs.getInt("age"));
                }
                rs.close();
                con.close();
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

The Log is here

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at com.bam.sqlex.JdbcConnectionExample.main(JdbcConnectionExample.java:14)
```

Comment: Make sure u have added driver jar file.

Answer (score 2):

May be u have not added jar of oracle driver [download jar from here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/index-091264.html)

Answer (score 0):

### java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver

Undoubtedly,  you are lack of Oralce jar, improt it into your project

Answer (score 0):

```
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
```

You have to check if this class is added to the classpath.